# Language Oriented Programming Articles/Papers/Tutorials

Tags: programming-languages, computer-science, dsl, mps

There is number of tools on the market like MPS, that promote Language Oriented Programming, which supposedly gives ability to programmer to design a (ideal?)language for task. This sounds interesting and boring at same time for some reason, so I was wondering if anyone know and can recommend articles regarding subject.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Language oriented programming*" is just a new term for quite an old and well-known concept. It is covered in detail in many Lisp textbooks. I'd recommend reading ["Practical Common Lisp"](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/), it is full of examples of using this approach. There is a huge volume of relevant papers produced by the Haskell community as well, like in [this](http://contracts.scheming.org/) example.

Answer (score 4):

Besides Language Oriented Programming, you can also search for Language Workbenches and Domain Specific Languages (DSLs).

For DSL's, Martin Fowler's latest book ("Domain Specific Languages") is the one to read.

On Language Oriented Programming, check Philipp W. Kutter's dissertation, ["Montages - Engineering of Computer Languages"](ftp://www.snm.ethz.ch/pub/people/thiele/paper/KutterDiss.pdf) (ftp). Check the [Cedallion](http://cedalion.sourceforge.net/) project too.

JetBrains' (creators of MPS) have a good article on the subject: http://www.onboard.jetbrains.com/articles/04/10/lop/

Answer (score 0):

The term "domain specific language" (and its precursor, "domain analysis") goes back to the work by James Neighbors on the [Draco](http://www.bayfronttechnologies.com/itt83p.pdf) system.

For a commercial version of this idea, see the discussion at [Domain Specific Languages](http://www.semdesigns.com/products/DMS/DomainSpecificLanguage.html) on how the Draco ideas have been built into our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit.